# Excel VBA: Exporting table data to Access. How to overwrite if the Primary Key of 2 fields already exist?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have webi report exported in .xlsx format with 3 tables from 3 tabs which I need to export to a Access Database.

The person who's going to run the webi report then copy the data from excel to access is located overseas and cannot open and work on the Access Database itself. (Has the access but latency issue makes things difficult)

The exported webi report cannot come with a macro, so I've created an Excel workbook with a single macro which will read the data from exported webi report then add it to the existing tables in Access Database.

Below code works if there are no 'matching primary keys' already in the database tables. But I need to improve it so it will overwrite any data with matching primary keys & create new entries for new primary keys.

What complicates things is that 2 of the 3 tables have 2 fields as the Primary Key, and the other table has 3 fields as Primary Key.

Could anyone help me with this issue please?
(If I can do this straight from WebI that would be fantastic but I couldn't find a working solution.)

Table1:

- mDate: Primary Key
- Country: Primary Key

Table2:

- mDate: Primary Key
- Country: Primary Key

Table3:

- mDate: Primary Key
- mTime: Primary Key
- Country: Primary Key

VBA Code:

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()

' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks("Exported_webi_Report")
Set wb1 = wb.Worksheets("tbl1")
Set wb2 = wb.Worksheets("tbl2")
Set wb3 = wb.Worksheets("tbl3")

' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=\\networkdrive\database.accdb;"


' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tbl1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(wb1.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = wb1.Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("Country") = wb1.Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("1") = wb1.Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("2") = wb1.Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("3") = wb1.Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("4") = wb1.Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("5") = wb1.Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("6") = wb1.Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("7") = wb1.Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("8") = wb1.Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("9") = wb1.Range("L" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing


' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tbl2", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(wb2.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = wb2.Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("Country") = wb2.Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("1") = wb2.Range("D" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tbl3", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(wb3.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = wb3.Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("mTime") = wb3.Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("Country") = wb3.Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("1") = wb3.Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("2") = wb3.Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("3") = wb3.Range("G" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT::

```
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tbl1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(wb1.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = wb1.Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("Country") = wb1.Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("1") = wb1.Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("2") = wb1.Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("3") = wb1.Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("4") = wb1.Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("5") = wb1.Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("6") = wb1.Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("7") = wb1.Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("8") = wb1.Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("9") = wb1.Range("L" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Following Tim's advice, I've changed above part of the code as below.

```
Dim sql As String, pk1 As Variant, pk2 As Variant, pk3 As Variant, pk As Variant

' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet

Do While Len(wb1.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs


        pk1 = wb1.Range("B" & r).Value
        pk2 = wb1.Range("C" & r).Value

        strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
                    "FROM tbl1 " & _
                    "WHERE [tbl1].[mDate] = # " & pk1 & " # " & _
                    "AND [tbl1].[Country] = ' " & pk2 & " ';"

        .Open Source:=strSQL, _
             ActiveConnection:=cn, _
             CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
             LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
             Options:=adCmdText

        'if EOF add new record otherwise overwrite old record
        If .EOF = True Then
            .AddNew 'Create a new record
        End If


        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = pk1
        .Fields("Country") = pk2
        .Fields("1") = wb1.Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("2") = wb1.Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("3") = wb1.Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("4") = wb1.Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("5") = wb1.Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("6") = wb1.Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("7") = wb1.Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("8") = wb1.Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("9") = wb1.Range("L" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

When run, it tries to add new data for existing dates and comes back with an error message saying that I'm trying to make a duplicate Primary Key.

EDIT #2

Continuing with Tim's instructions, I've closed the recordset inside each loop,(And no spaces between dates and #) as below.

```
Dim sql As String, pk1 As Variant, pk2 As Variant, pk3 As Variant, pk As Variant

' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' all records in a table
r = 8 ' the start row in the worksheet

Do While Len(wb1.Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs


        pk1 = wb1.Range("B" & r).Value
        pk2 = wb1.Range("C" & r).Value

        strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
                    "FROM tbl1 " & _
                    "WHERE [tbl1].[mDate] = #" & pk1 & "# " & _
                    "AND [tbl1].[Country] = ' " & pk2 & " ';"

        .Open Source:=strSQL, _
             ActiveConnection:=cn, _
             CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
             LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
             Options:=adCmdText

        'if EOF add new record otherwise overwrite old record
        If .EOF = True Then
            .AddNew 'Create a new record
        End If


        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("mDate") = pk1
        .Fields("Country") = pk2
        .Fields("1") = wb1.Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("2") = wb1.Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("3") = wb1.Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("4") = wb1.Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("5") = wb1.Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("6") = wb1.Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("7") = wb1.Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("8") = wb1.Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("9") = wb1.Range("L" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

Loop
```

Now, it worked well for last couple of days in August(30th and 31st).
But as soon as it encounters Sep 1st, it tries to create a new record and comes back with duplicate pk error.

What could I be doing wrong? I though it might be the date format so I tried to manually match all date formats which resulted the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For each table you'll need to run a query to see if there's an existing match (based on the primary key columns): if there is then update the retrieved record - if there isn't a match then add a new record; finally update the recordset with the updated/new record back to the database.  Rinse/repeat for each entry.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your help but I should have mentioned that I am completely new to Access and VBA. The codes above is a result of search, copy & paste. I can understand what you're instructing me but would you be able to write the code for me?

Comment: I don't have Access (or the spare time) so I cant write the code.  Change your recordset `Open` to use `select * from tblt t where [add where clause here using the PK fields]`  If the recordset is not EOF then you have a matching record, so update the  non-key fields.  If the recordset has no records (EOF is true) then use AddNew exactly as in your code (but the open/update/close needs to be inside the loop)

Comment: Hi Tim, Appreciate your help. I've tried to change the codes as you instructed, would you be able to review above and find out what I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: Are you sure your sql is finding the matches it should?  There should be no spaces between your date value and the #. Also, you should close the record set inside the loop

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Tim.
I've made the changes as above and made a good progress, but ran into the same issue on Sep 1st. Would you have any idea what could be causing this? I've copied the edited code above in the body.

Comment: Are you confident your sql is returning a record when it should?  It’s difficult to debug from here, not knowing what your exact datasets look like. Try picking one record where you know the expected outcome, and step through the code

Comment: I can confirm that this error only happens when the day is in single digit (from 1st to 9th). It works with any month as long as the day is in 2 digits. But I'm puzzled because I'm using default format for dates in my database and it shows the day in single digit as well (without zero in front.) The format of the date when I debug matches the format of the database.

Comment: Try formatting the date in your SQL to have a two digit day (and month?)

Comment: ...bottom line you need to first be sure your SQL is operating to identify the correct records.  Remember also you only need to update the PK fields if you add a new record (though i guess it doesn't harm either way...)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicates of `Table1` from Access database, try the code below.
(not tested)

```
dim sql as string, pk1 as variant, pk2 as variant, pk3 as variant, pk as variant
dim i as long

with wb1
    pk1 = application.transpose(.range(.range("B8"), .cells(.rows.count,2).end(xlup)).value)
    pk2 = application.transpose(.range(.range("B8"), .cells(.rows.count,2).end(xlup)).offset(,1).value)
end with

for i = lbound(pk1) to ubound(pk1)
    if pk1(i) > 0 then
        if isarray(pk) then
            redim preserve pk(ubound(pk)+1) as variant
        else
            redim pk(0) as variant
        end if
        pk(ubound(pk)) = "'" & format(pk1(i),"yyyymmdd") & "_" & pk2(i) & "'"
    else
        exit for
    end if
next i

sql = "DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE Format(mDate, ""yyyymmdd"") & ""_"" & country IN (" & join(pk, ", ") & ")"
cn.execute sql
```

Comment: Hi PW, Thanks for your help.
I'm getting a syntax error with below:
    sql = "DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE Format(mDate,"yyyymmdd") & "_" & country IN (" & join(pk, ", ") & ")"

Comment: Try: `sql = "DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE Format(mDate, ""yyyymmdd"") & ""_"" & country IN (" & join(pk, ", ") & ")"`

Comment: Thank you, PW.
I've made a good progress with your tip. However for some strange reasons, it's not deleting country fields named 'Others' & 'Philippines', which causes duplicate pk error.
Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @DanielHuh There are a lot of reasons to cause the error: maybe the typo or unnecessary white space appear in your Excel data.  If you want to debug, 
 error message is a good start.